# Ruby: string to array of integers

Tags: ruby

I want to convert a string into an array of integers. Why do I get an array of strings? What's the right way to achieve the result I'm looking for?

```
"1234".chars.each { |n| n.to_i }

=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `each` return the same array on which it was called. You need `map` here:

```
'1234'.chars.map(&:to_i)
```

which is a shorthand notation to:

```
'1234'.chars.map { |el| el.to_i }
```

and returns:

```
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As Cary Swoveland suggested, you can also use `each_char` method to prevent creation of additional array (`each_char` returns an enumerator):

```
'1234'.each_char.map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Perhaps `each_char` to avoid the creation of a temporary array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it's  your idea. Why don't you add it as an alternative answer? :)

Comment: Because it is a tiny detail.